# SOLVED: Keycloak + Spring Security OIDC Backchannel Logout: Unable to Trigger Redirect UI to Keycloak Login After SSO Session Max/ Idle

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak, openid-connect, oauth2client

I have a Spring Boot application that is configured as a Spring Security OAuth2 Client. I use Keycloak as my OIDC provider. I serve a compiled Angular application from my Spring Boot application. The Angular app keeps making requests every second to a REST API in the Spring Boot Application.

When the user opens this application in the browser at localhost:4881, they're redirected to the Keycloak login page and after a successful login, they're redirected back to localhost:4881 where the compiled Angular app is rendered.

When a user logs in, I see two sessions created in Keycloak, one called `Regular SSO` and the other `Offline`. The `Regular SSO` session gets cleared out as per the SSO Idle Timout. However, the Offline session remains for a longer duration in Keycloak but gets cleared from Keycloak eventually.

I am unable to redirect the UI to the Keycloak login page after the SSO Session Idle/ SSO Session Max timeout. My assumption is that Keycloak should communicate this session timeout event to the OAuth2 Client and the OAuth2 Client should redirect the UI to the Keycloak Login page for all following requests.

Can someone please tell me if I'm missing something here. I was unsuccessful in finding relevant documentation for this problem.

I set the `SSO Session Idle`, `SSO Session Max` and the `Offline Session Settings` at the realm level.
I've set the `Admin URL` in the client as well.

[image: Realm Settings]

[image: Client Settings]

**I have created a sample application with the exact same setup [here](https://github.com/sakethsusarla/keycloak-oauth2-client-ui)**: https://github.com/sakethsusarla/keycloak-oauth2-client-ui

`backend`: A Spring Boot Application configured as an OAuth2 Client, returns the current time through a REST API exposed at `/api/currentTime`

[image]

`frontend`: An Angular App that fetches current time from the backend

[image]

`realm`: The realm configuration is present in "keycloak-oauth2-client-ui\backend\src\main\resources\demo-realm.json"

The username and password to login are `demo` and `demo`

Comment: "I am unable to redirect the UI to the Keycloak login page after the SSO Session Idle/ SSO Session Max timeout." you mean you are not getting logout?

Comment: Yes, the user is not logged out. The session remains active. If the user tries to logout, then the logout works as expected. All data from the Spring Boot application is being fetched without any problem and the UI gets updated.

Comment: I found additional information regarding OIDC Back-channel Logout support in Spring Security [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/6.2-SNAPSHOT/servlet/oauth2/login/logout.html). It's not present in the stable release yet.

However, I haven't had luck in getting it to work so far. Still figuring out if I'm missing any configuration. 

I've made a new branch in the same git repo with these [changes](https://github.com/sakethsusarla/keycloak-oauth2-client-ui/tree/oidc-back-channel-logout)

Comment: Found some information about the offline sessions [here](https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/server_admin/topics/sessions/offline.html)

"The difference between a classic Refresh token and an Offline token is, that an offline token will never expire and is not subject of SSO Session Idle timeout . The offline token is valid even after a user logout or server restart."

Comment: A [thread](https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/session-expiration-and-backchannel-logout/18949) on the Keycloak Discourse group says that a session expiration in Keycloak does not trigger a backchannel logout request.

Answer (score 2):

After reading that Keycloak doesn't initiate a Backchannel Logout if a session expires, I decided to add a filter to check the validity of the token and invalidate the session if required.

Adding the following filter worked for me. I've updated my repository with the changes in the `main` [branch](https://github.com/sakethsusarla/keycloak-oauth2-client-ui).

```java
@Component
public class TokenExpirationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository oAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository;

    @Autowired
    TokenExpirationFilter(OAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository oAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository) {
        this.oAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository = oAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(@NonNull HttpServletRequest request, @NonNull HttpServletResponse response, @NonNull FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (authentication instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationToken token) {
            final OAuth2AuthorizedClient client =
                    oAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository.loadAuthorizedClient(
                            token.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(),
                            authentication,
                            request);

            final OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = client.getAccessToken();

            if (accessToken.getExpiresAt() != null && accessToken.getExpiresAt().isBefore(Instant.now())) {
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
                SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();

                final HttpSession httpSession = request.getSession();

                if (httpSession != null) {
                    httpSession.invalidate();
                }
            }
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution with the community